# er Why do we square for minimizing the difference between two values

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry If my question is too naive, I am learning Machine Learning course in that course instructor has taken a linear function

h(x) = theta + theta1(x)

here is an actual data

where x is the input which needs to be given

and y is the actual value and h(x) is a hypothetical value

inorder to reduce the difference between x and h(x) instructor proposed

to square the difference i.e. (h(x)-y)^2

If we consider if its is being solely done to encounter the negative values but It would give me wrong output when I consider the case

h(x) > y, h(x)-y>0 and if we square it (h(x)-y)^2 would be even more isnt it?

Why is it being done, I am unable to understand.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Siddartha C.S

Answer (score 1):

This is so that if $h(x)=y$, $(h(x)-y)^2$ is `0` and *greater* than $0$ otherwise, i.e. $h(x)=y$ is the minimum. If we don't square it, then we might find some $h(x)<y$ which would appear to be a better solution than the actual solution.

We could also minimise $|h(x)-y|$.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for the response in your case if h(x)=y then the difference of h(x) and y would be zero how it can be greater than zero? may be I am missing something please clarify

Comment: Looking for $x$ such that $h(x)=y$. If $h(x)>y$ then $h(x)-y > 0$ but if $h(x)<y$ then $h(x)-y<0$, which would be *more minimal* than the actual solution.

Minimising would find the _most negative_ solution, where as we want the nearest to zero. Alternativly we could take the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of $h(x)-y$.